# Slide animate background color left to right UIView or UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

How to slide animate background color left to right UIView or UIButton Swift (iOS)

Example of animating:

```css
div {
    font: 22px Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: red; /* default color */

    /* "to left" / "to right" - affects initial color */
    background: linear-gradient(to left, salmon 50%, lightblue 50%) right;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}
div:hover {
    background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<div>Example</div>
```

Comment: Please review [ask]. Describe *exactly* what you want to do; describe what you've tried so far (from researching it) and describe what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AnimatingButton: UIView {

func startProgressAnimation()
{
    let layer = CALayer()
    layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4980392157, green: 0.8352941176, blue: 0.1921568627, alpha: 1)
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.anchorPoint = .zero
    

    layer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0,
                              y: 0,
                              width: self.frame.width,
                              height: self.frame.height)
    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    
    let boundsAnim:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
    boundsAnim.fromValue = 0
    boundsAnim.toValue = self.frame.size.width
    let anim = CAAnimationGroup()
    anim.animations = [boundsAnim]
    anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    anim.duration = 10
    
    layer.add(anim, forKey: "bounds.size.width")
}}
```